# In Nastran, how to ignore fatal error due to failed convergence and move on to next subcase?

Tags: structural-analysis, finite-element-method, aerospace-engineering, nastran

At the moment the whole analysis stops when 1 subcase fails to converge. How can I keep the analysis going such that all subcases are are run, even if they all might produce an error?

I'm pretty sure there is a command for this to write in the case control section.

All help would be appreciated, thanks!